# solving quation : Summation of variables equals k (with conditions)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm solving a problem and the way I'm solving it ends up with this equation:

$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... + x_{n-1} = k 
$$

$$
0 \le x_i \le i
$$

and k is an integer (It can be all integer values from 0 to ${n \choose 2}$)

Is there any exact formula for the number of solutions (for a given n and k) ?

Comment: Do you want a formula telling you values of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ satisfying this system, or do you want a formula telling you how many solutions there are?  (There are generally very many solutions.  For $n=3$, every point on the line through $(0,k)$ and $(k,0)$ is a solution.)

Comment: I'm looking for count of all solutions (I'm calculating probability)

Comment: Is the domain of the $x_i$ constrained in some way?  Perhaps they are required to be integers?

Comment: they are integers , this is discrete math question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of solutions for particular values of $n$ and $k$.  What can we figure out about $f$?

- First a lower bound, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 0 = 0$, so 
  $$  f(n,k) = 0, \qquad k < 0  \text{.}  $$
- For $k=0$, there is only one choice of the $x_i$s, and that's "all $0$".  This is only possible for $n \geq 1$, so \begin{align*}
      f(n,0) = 1, \qquad n \geq 1  \\
      f(n,0) = 0, \qquad n < 1  \text{.}
  \end{align*}
- Now, an upper bound, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \binom{n}{2}$, so
  $$  f(n,k) = 0, \qquad k > \binom{n}{2}  \text{.}  $$
- If $0 < k \leq \binom{n}{2}$, then we can run through the choices for $x_{n-1}$ and sum the number of ways to write $k = x_{n-1}$ in terms of $x_1, \dots, x_{n-2}$.  This is also true when $0 < k < n$, since, by the above, we will get $0$s for the too large choices of $x_{n-1}$.  (That is, when $k - x_{n-1} < 0$, we will get a $0$ summand.)
  $$  f(n,k) = \sum_{x_{n-1} = 0}^{n-1} f(n-1, k - x_{n-1}) \qquad, 0 < k \leq \binom{n}{2}  $$

We use the above to generate some test values (and to catch simple errors)

- $f(0,k) = 0$ -- no sum can be written as a sum of $-1$ terms.
- $f(1,0) = 1$ and $f(1,1) = 0$ -- the only sum of zero terms is $0$.
- $f(2,0) = 1$, $f(2,1) = 1$, and $f(2,2) = 0$ -- a sum of only one term can be either $0$ or $1$, each in only one way.
- $f(3,0) = 1$, $f(3,1) = 2$, ($0+1$ or $1+0$), $f(3,2) = 2$, ($1+1$ or $0+2$), and $f(3,3) = 1$.

For $n \geq 1$ and $k=1$, there are $n-1$ choices for where to put the "$1$" in the sum, so $$  f(n,1) = n-1, n \geq 1  \text{.}  $$  Alternatively, for $n > 1$, $f(n,1)$ $= f(n-1,0) + f(n-1,1)$ $= 1+(n-2)$ $= n-1$, by induction, with the results of $f(1,0)$ and $f(1,1)$, above, giving the $n=1$ case.

For $n \geq 3$ and $k=2$, $f(n,2)$ $= f(n-1,0) + f(n-1,1) + f(n-1,2)$ $= 1 + (n-2) + f(n-1,2)$.  The recurrence $f(3,2)$ $= 2$, $f(n,2)$ $= f(n-1,2) + n-1$ has solution $$  f(n,2) = \frac{1}{2}(n^2 - n - 2), n \geq 3  \text{.}  $$

For $n \geq 3$ and $k = 3$, $f(n,3)$ $= f(n-1,0) + f(n-1,1) + f(n-1,2) + f(n-1,3) $ $= 1 + (n-2) + \frac{1}{2}((n-1)^2 + (n-1) - 2) + f(n-1,3)$ $= \frac{1}{2}(n^2-n-2) + f(n-1,3)$.  With $f(3,3) = 1$, this has solution $$  f(n,3) = \frac{1}{6}(n^3 - 7n), n \geq 3  \text{.}  $$

The upper bound condition $f(n,k) = 0, k > \binom{n}{2}$ tells us the first $n$ (for fixed $k$) which is nonzero, so we know where to start subsequent paragraphs.  For $k=4$, the pattern of summands is still straightforward.  So we get 
$$  f(n,4) = \frac{1}{24} n(n+1)(n^2+n-14), n \geq 4  $$

Here we encounter a new difficulty.  The initial nonzero case for $k=4$ was the first for which the sum of the prior formulas didn't include all of them.  However, for the induction, that sum did.  For $k=5$, this is no longer the case.  $f(4,5) = 3$ and $f(5,5) = 22 = 3+5+6+5+3$, which excludes $f(4,0) = 1$.

Nevertheless we could continue, getting $f(n,k) = \frac{1}{k!} (n^k \pm \cdots)$ for higher and higher $k$, but I see no way to assemble these polynomials into a closed form.  Nor do I know a theorem that asserts that no such form exists.

As an aside, numerical experiments suggest $f(n,k)$ is well approximated by $\frac{1}{k!} (n-1)^k$, with monotonically decreasing relative error for fixed $k$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  For fixed $n$, the relative error increases up to the (symmetric) maximum value in $k$, then decreases.